# Is it possible to print an argument being passed to map if a condition matches?

Tags: python

I am wondering if it is possible to get arguments being passed to a map function in python if a condition matches. Take this code as an example:

```
from requests import get

for res in map(get, ['https://google.com', 'https://bing.com']):
    if 'google' in res.text:
        # print 'https://google.com' here
```

I know i can do this in a `for` loop, but I am trying to use `map` to maximize performance.

Comment: Start by printing out `res` and then locate the webpage in the headers/response and use `res.headers.origin` or whatever you need?

Comment: You ARE using a `for` loop though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either get the data from the `request` attribute of the response object, or you can decorate or otherwise modify/extend `get` or `map`to print before executing the rest of the function.

I would go with checking the `request` attribute of the response object.

Comment: This was a great suggestion! `res.url` or `res.request.url` gives me the url for the request.

Answer (score 2):

> I know i can do this in a for loop, but I am trying to use map to maximize performance.

Don't!

Consider the task of downloading a web page. A request has to go out and return a response. This can take anywhere from milliseconds to seconds. Changing your code to use `map` might shave a microsecond off each iteration, What's the point here?

I timed the following two pieces of code, with the results shown. Is this really worth making your program more difficult to read? Conventional Pythonic wisdom would suggest not.

```
lst = []
for s in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
    lst.append(nofunc(s))
```

1.16 µs ± 16.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

```
lst = []
for s in map(nofunc, ('1', '2', '3', '4')):
    lst.append(s)
```

1.3 µs ± 13.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Donald Knuth famously wrote "premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming." You have better things to worry about.

Comment: Well said! And i fully agree! But in this case, my list of urls can be quite big.. about 40+, and not all the servers respond with the same efficiency as others... so in order to prevent a lock, and add a hint of optimization, I am taking this approach. If i was working with other types of data sets, I would fully agree with using a standard for loop

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming" is one of the best Knuth quotes I've ever heard. thanks for sharing.

Comment: Without using threading or some other asynchronous technique, `map` won't save you any time since each web access has to wait until the one before it has finished. I don't understand what kind of speedup you would expect over a list of 40+ URLs, nor why locks come into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from requests import get

urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://bing.com']
for url, res in zip(urls, map(get, urls)):
    if 'google' in res.text:
        # print 'https://google.com' here
        print url
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid. This is because my list of urls are a lot bigger than 2 and using map significantly improves performance. as stated in the original question

Comment: I think probably you can reduce the performance issue by using `tuple` instead of the `list`, or `imap` and `izip` in the `itertools` module. But I am not pretty sure these code has some performance issues, could you show me ?